# Why is $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{15} = \frac{15}{30} - \frac{10}{30}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Sorry I am a math newbie.

Why is 
$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{15} = \frac{15}{30} - \frac{10}{30}?$$

Comment: Can you appreciate why $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{15}{30}$ are the same number?

Comment: You need to do these separately: $\frac12 = \frac{15}{30}$ and $\frac{5}{15} = \frac{10}{30}$.  Then subtract.

Comment: "1 out of 2" is the same as "15 out of 30" since each "numerator" (top of the fraction) is exactly half the "denominator" (bottom of the fraction). Same goes for the other fraction. "5 out of 15" is the same as "10 out of 30" since the numerator and denominator of the former are half those of the latter. Basically if you take any fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ and multiply by $\frac{c}{c}$ you get $\frac{ac}{bc}=\frac{x}{y}$ and $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x}{y}$. They are different representations of the same value.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{15} &= \frac {15}{15}\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ -\ \, \frac22 \times \left(\frac{5}{15}\right) \\
& = \frac {15}{30} \ - \ \,\frac{10}{30}\\
& =\frac{15- 10}{30}\\
&= \frac 5{30}\\
& =\frac16
\end{align}

Comment: @b00n heT Thanks for editing.

Comment: You are welcome :) the align enironment is nicely suited for multiple-row expressions

Answer (score 1):

This fact follows from the nature of fractions.

The short answer is that the value of a fraction doesnt change if you multiply both the nominator and the denominator with the same non-zero number.

So

$$
\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1\cdot 2}{2\cdot 2}=\frac{2}{4}
$$

you could also multiply with $3$ for example

$$
\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 3}=\frac{3}{6}
$$

More generally

$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a\cdot n}{b\cdot n}, \qquad where \quad b,n\neq 0
$$

So in your exact example

$$
\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1\cdot 15}{2\cdot 15}=\frac{15}{30}
$$

and

$$
\frac{5}{15}=\frac{5\cdot 2}{15\cdot 2}=\frac{10}{30}.
$$

A more complicated answer would say that fractions are partitioned into equivalence classes where the equivalence relation would be

$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\iff ad=bc, \qquad where \quad b,d\neq 0
$$

and fractions being in the same equivalence class are considered having the same value (you surely not after the complicated answer I just added it for completeness sake)

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, two fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are all integers and $b,d$ are both nonzero are *defined* to be equal if and only if $ad = bc$.  You  have as a result things like $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{15}{30}=\frac{1300}{2600}=\dots$

We can then further *define* subtraction of two fractions as $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}$ where the subtraction and multiplication that occur within the numerator and denominator are the usual operations as defined for integers.

In your case $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{5}{15}=\frac{1\cdot 15 - 2\cdot 5}{2\cdot 15} = \frac{15-10}{30}=\frac{5}{30}$ which can be seen to be equal to $\frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

Get common denominators because multiplying a number by $1$, does not change its value so multiple the top (numerator) and the bottom (denominator) with the same number:

$\frac{1*15}{2*15}=\frac{15}{30}$ see how the value does not change as $\frac{15}{15}=1$ and multiplying by $1$ does not change value.

$\frac{5*2}{15*2}=\frac{10}{30}$ just like above, $\frac{2}{2}=1$ and multiplying by $1$ does not change value of your number.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On the left side is $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{15}$. Half of the small squares are coloured, but $5$ blocks of rectangles have been removed, where each block is one $\frac{1}{15}$th or $\frac{2}{30}$th of the whole part.

On the right side is $\frac{15}{30} - \frac{10}{30}$. $15$ of the small squares have been coloured, but $10$ of them have been removed.

The two pictures are exactly the same, hence $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{15} = \frac{15}{30} - \frac{10}{30}$.

Comment: In principle II like this answer for a fraction newbie, but the pictures are confusing and identical. Both have 36 small sqyares, not 30.

Comment: I just realised I can't count.

Comment: Does this look better to you?

Comment: The two pictures still look identical. I don't (easily) see $5/15$ on the left. The green is $5/30$ and the red is $10/30$. You and I know that is $5/15$ but explaining that to the OP is the whole point. I'd start with a $3\times 5 $ rectangle with $5$ some boxes selected, Then trying to cut that in half means halving some boxes. That suggests halving them all, which is why you end up with $30$ths.